# Scope problems / "Undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, oop, geolocation

For my new project, I'm learning to work with objects in Javascript. So far, I've made a pretty big mess of it all and was hoping somebody could point out what's going wrong.

My main code:

```
var self = null;    //to force a local 'self' variable from now on

var Person = function (firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;

    this.user_lat = 0;
    this.user_long = 0;
    this.user_accur = 0;
    this.user_stable = 0;       

};

Person.prototype.setCoordinates = function(lat, lng) {
    this.user_lat = lat;
    this.user_long = lng;
}

Person.prototype.fetchLocation = function() {
    var self = this;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(self.logPosition, function() { console.log("position fail") }, {enableHighAccuracy: true});
}


Person.prototype.logPosition = function(pos) {   //saves coordinates in current person - object
    this.setCoordinates(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
}
```

index.php does the following:

```
var person = new Person("Lorre");
person.fetchLocation();
//do_stuff_with_location_in_object
```

However, the 'setcoordinates' function fails and gives an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function / main.js:40 / Person.logPosition
```

I'm pretty sure it's something stupid I'm doing wrong, but I've been struggling with "this"'es all evening now and I'm getting desperate... Hope any of you can see what's going wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please indent your code, I think you have some misplaced braces

Comment: getCurrentPosition(self.logPosition.bind(self) ,

Comment: `var self = this;` is the beginning of maintaining the same `this` in a callback, but you have to add a second wrapper to use it, i.e. `function (pos) { self.logPosition(pos); }` rather than `self.logPosition`. `this.logPosition.bind(this)` works too, though.

Comment: Taking the answer from the comments was legit and answering own questions is fine on SO. Your attribution to minitech and dandavis was correct, but misinterpreted by some users as a `thank you` "answer". You might improve your answer and undelete it since every deleted answer counts against you. I could vote for undelete, but it was your decision I have to respect.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit.Instead of inserting an answer into the question, please undelete your answer, you might rephrase, keep the attribution and make clear it was taken from the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dandavis and minitech for helping in the comments. `bind(this)` did the trick!

```
this.logPosition.bind(this)
```

Comment: This is not a thank you as answer, but taking an answer from the comments as real answer.